# polars equivalent of pandas groupby.apply(drop_duplicates)

Tags: python, group-by, aggregate, python-polars, drop-duplicates

I am new to polars and I wonder  what is the equivalent of pandas groupby.apply(drop_duplicates) in polars.
Here is the code snippet I need to translate :

```
import pandas as pd

GROUP = list('123231232121212321')
OPERATION = list('AAABBABAAAABBABBBA')
BATCH = list('777898897889878987')

df_input = pd.DataFrame({'GROUP':GROUP, 'OPERATION':OPERATION, 'BATCH':BATCH})
df_output = df_input.groupby('GROUP').apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates())
```

[input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1th6.png)
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2qsN.png)

I tried the following, but, it does not output what I need

```
import polars as pl

GROUP = list('123231232121212321')
OPERATION = list('AAABBABAAAABBABBBA')
BATCH = list('777898897889878987')

df_input = pl.DataFrame({'GROUP':GROUP, 'OPERATION':OPERATION, 'BATCH':BATCH})
df_output = df_input.groupby('GROUP').agg(pl.all().unique())
```

If I take only one Group, I get locally what I want :

```
df_part = df_input.filter(pl.col('GROUP')=='2')
df_part[['OPERATION', 'BATCH']].unique()
```

Does somebody know how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want the first instance of each `OPERATION, BATCH` "pairing" per `GROUP`

You can use `pl.struct` to create the "pairing", and then `.is_first().over("GROUP")`

```
(df.with_row_count()
   .filter(pl.struct("OPERATION", "BATCH").is_first().over("GROUP")))
```

```
shape: (9, 4)
┌────────┬───────┬───────────┬───────┐
│ row_nr ┆ GROUP ┆ OPERATION ┆ BATCH │
│ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---       ┆ ---   │
│ u32    ┆ str   ┆ str       ┆ str   │
╞════════╪═══════╪═══════════╪═══════╡
│ 0      ┆ 1     ┆ A         ┆ 7     │
│ 1      ┆ 2     ┆ A         ┆ 7     │
│ 2      ┆ 3     ┆ A         ┆ 7     │
│ 3      ┆ 2     ┆ B         ┆ 8     │
│ 4      ┆ 3     ┆ B         ┆ 9     │
│ 5      ┆ 1     ┆ A         ┆ 8     │
│ 7      ┆ 3     ┆ A         ┆ 9     │
│ 10     ┆ 2     ┆ A         ┆ 8     │
│ 11     ┆ 1     ┆ B         ┆ 9     │
└────────┴───────┴───────────┴───────┘
```

The `.with_row_count` is just added to show what rows were kept/removed.

Comment: Hi, I Just needed to add some brackets to make it work :
(df.with_row_count()
   .filter(pl.struct(["OPERATION", "BATCH"]).is_first().over("GROUP")))
Speed increased by a factor of ten compared to my answer, thank you for your answer !

Comment: @Upsikan Are there other columns in your real data? Because your example can be solved with just: `df.unique()` - this answer is assuming you want to perform the unique/duplicate check on a subset of columns.

Comment: What I initially intended to do can indeed be solved by df.unique(). However your main answer gives the opportunity to keep additional variables (such as an ID in my case), which could be beneficial, for double checking. When it comes to performance df.unique is 10 times faster, so I'll use that solution.
In any case I learnt how to use struct, thank you a lot !

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to do this is to just use `unique(subset=[])`, potentially with the optional `maintain_order=True` and `keep='first'`

For instance,

```
df_input.unique(['OPERATION','BATCH','GROUP'],maintain_order=True, keep='first')

shape: (9, 3)
┌───────┬───────────┬───────┐
│ GROUP ┆ OPERATION ┆ BATCH │
│ ---   ┆ ---       ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ str       ┆ str   │
╞═══════╪═══════════╪═══════╡
│ 1     ┆ A         ┆ 7     │
│ 2     ┆ A         ┆ 7     │
│ 3     ┆ A         ┆ 7     │
│ 2     ┆ B         ┆ 8     │
│ 3     ┆ B         ┆ 9     │
│ 1     ┆ A         ┆ 8     │
│ 3     ┆ A         ┆ 9     │
│ 2     ┆ A         ┆ 8     │
│ 1     ┆ B         ┆ 9     │
└───────┴───────────┴───────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it :

```
import polars as pl

GROUP = list('123231232121212321')
OPERATION = list('AAABBABAAAABBABBBA')
BATCH = list('777898897889878987')

df_input = pl.DataFrame({'GROUP':GROUP, 'OPERATION':OPERATION, 'BATCH':BATCH})
df_output = df_input.groupby('GROUP').apply(lambda x: x.unique())
df_output.sort(by ='GROUP')
```

Please let me know if you find another way to do it ! I guess it could be more efficient.